# How to create a Map (Hashtable) that concatenates values to vectors if same key? (example inside)

Tags: matlab, hashmap, hashtable, vectorization

I am trying to create a hash table that concatenates a value to a vector based on a key (see example).

So there is a [Map Class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html#bt23jk1-5) in matlab that behaves like this (you can copy-paste this into matlab):

```
% I create my first map
keySet =   {'333', '145', '6', '34'}; 
valueSet1 = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4]; 
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet1)

% Create second map with one or more shared keys (see '333' is a repeated key)
keySet   = {'333','15','765'}; 
valueSet = [ 69.9, 32.3, 37.3]; 
newMap = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);

% Concatanate these maps
mapObj = [mapObj; newMap];

% The results look like this:
[keys(mapObj)',values(mapObj)'] 

%     [  6]    [197.6000]
%     [ 15]    [ 32.3000]
%     [ 34]    [178.4000]
%     [145]    [368.2000]
%     [333]    [69.9000]
%     [765]    [ 37.3000]
```

You see how the value `327.2` for the key `'333'` was replaced by `69.9`?

What I am **trying to do is to concatenate** any values with a shared key so that the output look like:

```
[keys(mapObj)',values(mapObj)'] 

%     [  6]    [197.6000]
%     [ 15]    [ 32.3000]
%     [ 34]    [178.4000]
%     [145]    [368.2000]
%     [333]    [327.2000, 69.9000]     <<<<<< This is what i'm trying to do
%     [765]    [ 37.3000]
```

But I can't figure out how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial solution is to make your own map joining helper function that checks for shared keys between the two maps and concatenates them if necessary.

For example:

```
function outMap = mapjoin(map1, map2)
sharedkeys = intersect(map1.keys, map2.keys);

outMap = [map1; map2];
if ~isempty(sharedkeys)
    for ii = 1:numel(sharedkeys)
        key = sharedkeys{ii};
        outMap(key) = [map1(key) map2(key)];
    end
end
end
```

Provides the desired outcome:

```
ans =

  6×2 cell array

    {'145'}    {[368.2000]}
    {'15' }    {[ 32.3000]}
    {'333'}    {1×2 double}
    {'34' }    {[178.4000]}
    {'6'  }    {[197.6000]}
    {'765'}    {[ 37.3000]}

>> newMap('333')

ans =

  327.2000   69.9000
```

Note that you'll need to set [`'UniformValues'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html#inputarg_UniformValues) to `false` in your `containers.map` generation, otherwise you will receive errors if all of your values are scalar and you attempt to concatenate two keys together.

For example:

```
>> A = containers.Map('foo', 42);
>> A('foo') = [A('foo') 3.14]
Error using containers.Map/subsasgn
Specified value type does not match the type expected for this container.

>> A = containers.Map('foo', 42, 'UniformValues', false);
>> A('foo') = [A('foo') 3.14];
>> A('foo')

ans =

   42.0000    3.1400
```

Comment: Not ideal, but very elegant solution. Thanks